# Do not ask for optional argument when autocompleting

Tags: emacs

I have Emacs 24.4.1 with the following packages so to get autocompletion:

- yasnippet
- auto-complete
- auto-complete-auctex

(and of course AUCTeX)

After I type `\usep` and then press TAB, the string is autocompleted to

```
\usepackage[opt1,...]{Package}
```

Instead of this behavior I'd like the following:

```
\usepackage{Package}
```

What option should I change to achieve the desired behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are on a UNIX system and you have installed auto-complete-auctex manually (say by copying the .el file in the `.emacs.d` folder and then loading it from your `.emacs` file), you can simply edit the .el file and change the unwanted completion. The relevant line to edit is line 49:

```
(LaTeX-arg-usepackage . (["opt1,..."] "Package"))
```

change it to

```
(LaTeX-arg-usepackage . ("Package"))
```

restart Emacs and you're all set.

Note that if you installed the auto-complete-auctex package via the package system I'm not sure this method will work (I'd suggest you to install this package manually because is such a simple package it will do no harm).

Note also that I have no idea about how all this works for non-UNIX systems.

Answer (score 1):

> After I type \usep and then press TAB, the string is autocompleted to ...

Wrong approach. Don't type `\usep`, but type C-c C-m and then `usep` and tab. Because auctex has its own machinery for completion of packages.

Comment: I don't want AUCTeX built in completion system, I want the one provided by the auto-complete package.